# Clickable image map in Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll, imagemap

I would like to add a clickable map to my jekyll site on github.

For example, a map of the US which I click to reach an anchor tag
containing text related to the state clicked.

An example of what I hope to end up with is at: 
http://wilsonmar.github.io/museums-roadtrip-usa/

There are two different approaches: HTML and CSS.

Are there examples of either for jekyll hosted on github pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to generate an html image-map with Jekyll, you can use collections.

file: _us-states/alaska.md

```
---
name: Alaska
abbrev: AK
coord: "52,249,42,253,..."
---
Your text here
```

An you generate your image-map like this :

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Us states" usemap="#us-states" />
<map name="us-states">
{% for s in site.collections['us-states'] %}
    <area shape="poly" coords="{{ s.map.coord }}" 
          href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ s.url }}" 
          alt="{{ s.name }}" title="{{ s.name }}" >
{% endfor %}
</map>
```

Comment: Freakin' brilliant answer. BTW, </map> needs to be at the bottom to complete the picture.

Comment: Good catch @WilsonMar

Comment: Sorry, David. In the HTML that ends up in the browser, no map data is shown, as in: <img src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/300046/14015545/77b35900-f17f-11e5-83b7-f931da813eb2.gif" alt="USA states" usemap="#us-states" /></p>
<map name="us-states">

</map>

Comment: Without the complete code, it's difficult to spot the problem.

Comment: The markdown file is at https://github.com/wilsonmar/wilsonmar.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-03-19-museums-roadtrip-usa.md US_states_map

Comment: To make things easier, I put the code here: https://github.com/wilsonmar/wilsonmar.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-02-01-clickable-maps-in-jekyll-posts.md

Comment: Seems that there is no `us-states` collection in your site. Create an`us-states` [collection](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/). Create one collection page by state and it will work.

Comment: Maybe I didn't format the file correctly. It's at http://wilsonmar.github.io/assets/us-states (no file extension)

Comment: I think I understand my misunderstanding. I was thinking that collections are separate lines in a file, such as what I created at  http://wilsonmar.github.io/assets/us-states (no file extension)

title: US States map areas
states:
   - coords: "264,157,286,155,292,193,276,195,270,199,264,157" 
   title: "Alabama" 
   href: "#AL"
   alt: "AL = Alabama"
   - coords: "28,197,46,185,72,199,72,241,88,243,102,261,92,263,70,241,42,243,28,25
etc.

However, it looks like collection is about collection data from inside several files. I'll work on this.